# dynamically change the value of a dimens.xml property within activity in android app

Tags: java, android, xml, reference

My goal is to alter the number of columns that my gridView will display. In the gridView XML layout, i reference a value from my dimens.xml to set numColumns. Is there a way to reference this value from dimens xml to change its value? Being new to android development, maybe there is a better way to control the value for numColumns.

all help is appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the values in dimens.xml on runtime. However you can change the number of columns in gridview using code. Below is the java method that you can call from your fragment or any class to change the number of columns
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setNumColumns(int)